# jQuery Mobile: Grid layouts

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I currently need a solution which allows a collapsable div based on the option set. The idea was a div with on the left text and on the right the options.

I have implemented the grid layout:

```
<li>
 <div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a">Do you require ............... &pound;1 </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b"><input type="radio" name="label" value="yes" />Yes<input type="radio" name="label" value="no" />No</div>
 </div>
</li>
```

but I require `ui-block-a` to be 70% and `ui-block-b` to be 30%

I have tried adding the following to the CSS to try and reset it but it doesn't want to work:

```
.ui-block-a{
width:70%;
}
.ui-block-b{
width:30%;
}
```

does anyone know of a way to do this? or is it just as simple as changing the class name to a custom class or are there other elements I would need to add to get the same effect as `.ui-block-b` & `.ui.block-a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `!important` in your css on the classes:

### JSFIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/tronc/pPmr5/1/

Comment: actually i have just realised that this reverts back to the original 50% & 50% view and doesn't actually give the element 70% 30%

Comment: add some more code in your question or explain when this is happening.

Comment: Ignore me I'm being a complete idiot. For some reason i had a moment and put <script src="style.css"></script> instead of link